# User Impersonation using Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

How can I retrieve records behalf of another user.

```js
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", "?$select=name&$top=3").then(
    function success(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
            console.log(result.entities[i]);
        }                    
        // perform additional operations on retrieved records
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // handle error conditions
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know we can do impersonation using `XMLHttpRequest` by passing `MSCRMCallerID` header. Not sure we can achieve the same in `Xrm.WebApi`.

This is my Prod code, doing some update/assign operation under Admin impersonation from a HTML webresource.

```
var entity = {};
entity["ownerid@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(" + currentUserId + ")";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", parent.Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/new_customentity(" + opptyid + ")", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("MSCRMCallerID", "0AFB2F7E-D323-E511-80F0-C4346BAC29F0"); //CRM Admin impersoantion
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            //Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

**Update**

Passing header is the only way and `Xrm.WebApi` cannot accept request headers.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/impersonate-another-user-web-api#how-to-impersonate-a-user) says:

> There are two ways you can impersonate a user, both of which are made possible by passing in a header with the corresponding user id.
>
> **Preferred**: Impersonate a user based on their Azure Active Directory (AAD) object id by passing that value along with the header `CallerObjectId`.
> **Legacy**: To impersonate a user based on their systemuserid you can leverage `MSCRMCallerID` with the corresponding guid value.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yah! That is correct. But looking to Xrm.WebApi.

Comment: @Sidhu last time when I checked it was not there.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Arun. I am checking on this.

Comment: @Sidhu how did that go?